# How to get all students whose mark is greater than particular student

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table called `students` and it is looks like below.

```
id name mark 
1   A    10
2   B    20
3   C    30
4   D    40
```

Now, How can I get all students whose marks is greater than student name 'B'. I can do with below query.

```
SELECT * from student WHERE mark > (SELECT mark FROM student WHERE name = 'B');
```

Is it possible without sub query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is with a `INNER JOIN` by double joining the table like below

```
SELECT s.* 
from student s
join student s1
on s.mark > s1.mark
and s1.name = 'B';
```

(OR) Using `WHERE EXISTS` like

```
SELECT * from student s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                FROM student 
                WHERE name = 'B'
                AND s.mark > mark);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a stored procedure to store the mark of student B into a variable, then use that variable in the WHERE clause of the first query.

However, I think subqueries would be the best way.

Why would you want to avoid using a subquery?

Comment: Why do you need a stored procedure for this?

Comment: You don't need one, but that's just an alternative to using a subquery. I think that using a subquery is better. Also your answer using the join is something I didn't consider.